# Singleton dictionary is not being singleton

Tags: c#, .net, dictionary, singleton, access-token

I have a dictionary in a singleton class. I am saving there the pair , every time I access to that dictionary from the method that is creating the token it shows all the credentials that I've stored there.

But when I access from another class in another project of the solutions it displays the dictionary empty. Can anybody tell me why this happens?

**This is the class that manage the dictionary:**

```
public class UserAccessToken
{
    public Dictionary<string, string> UserDictionary { get; set; }

    private static UserAccessToken _instance;

    private UserAccessToken() { }

    public static UserAccessToken Instance
    {
        get
        {
            if (_instance == null)
                _instance = new UserAccessToken
                {
                    UserDictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>()
                };
            return _instance;
        }
    }
}
```

**This is the method that insert the key,value pair in the dictionary:**

```
public override Task TokenEndpointResponse(OAuthTokenEndpointResponseContext context)
    {
        var accessToken = context.AccessToken;

        if (context.Properties.Dictionary.ContainsKey("userName"))
        {
            var username = context.Properties.Dictionary["userName"];
            // If I access here multiple times the singleton works
            UserAccessToken.Instance.UserDictionary[username] = accessToken;
        }
        return Task.FromResult<object>(null);
    }
```

**This is the method where I access the dictionary, from here I can see that it's empty:**

```
private bool IsTokenValid(HttpContextBase httpContext)
    {
        var username = httpContext.User.Identity.Name;
        var userTokens = UserAccessToken.Instance.UserDictionary;
        var tokenToAccess = httpContext.Request.Headers["Authorization"];
        tokenToAccess = tokenToAccess.Replace("Bearer ", "");
        if (userTokens.ContainsKey(username))
        {
            var token = userTokens[username];
            if (token == tokenToAccess) return true;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: Are the two accesses on the same thread? You're singleton implementation is not thread-safe.

Comment: _"from another class in another project"_ so it's probably also another **process**? Of course your `Instance` is not the same for different processes.

Comment: Jon Skeet has a [great section](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Singleton.aspx) about singletons in C# In Depth.  Check out the thread safe examples (my favorite is using `Lazy<T>`)

Comment: Please read [MCVE] guidance on posting code. There is way too much unrelated code shown and really not enough information to understand the problem. I.e. as @RenéVogt pointed out the code may be running in separate processes or at least separate threads (as code shown is using non-thread safe `Dictionary` without locking)...  Note that code as shown would work fine if executed synchronously on the same thread in one process.

Comment: Also you are using Dictionary class. You will get issues if 2 threads are adding/updating user tokenat the same time. You should switch to ConcurrentDictionary

Comment: I also tried with ConcurrentDictionary  and nothing, that class that manage the dictionary is in one proyect below in inheritance of the other two projects that are accessing, maybe the problem is that they are in different process, but is there any way to make this happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I already solved my problem, but I'll let my solution here in case could be useful for somebody.

The problem is that if you are running two different projects, that will mean two different process, so, what I wanted to do is pretty impossible. I used [Redis](https://redis.io/documentation) for this and it is working well.

This is an example of Redis use:

```
public class CallManagerCache : ICallManagerMethods{


    private static Lazy<ConnectionMultiplexer> lazyConnection = new Lazy<ConnectionMultiplexer>(() => ConnectionMultiplexer
        .Connect(CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("RedisConnectionString")));

    public static ConnectionMultiplexer cacheConnection
    {
        get
        {
            return lazyConnection.Value;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    ///     Here you save the value in cache, you get the connection, then StringSetAsync is in charge of saving the value
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="name"></param>
    /// <param name="template"></param>
    public async Task UpdateCallInstance(int id, byte[] data, bool instanceForCallback = false, TimeSpan? timespan = null)
    {
        var cache = cacheConnection.GetDatabase();
        await cache.StringSetAsync(instanceForCallback ? $"Call_{id}" : id.ToString(), data, timespan ?? new TimeSpan(0, 0, 15, 0));
    }

    /// <summary>
    ///     Here you get the value in cache, you get the connection, then StringGetAsync is in charge of getting the value
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="name"></param>
    /// <param name="template"></param>
    public async Task<CallInstance> GetById(int id, bool isForCallback)
    {
        var cache = cacheConnection.GetDatabase();

        var callInstance = new CallInstance
        {
            Id = id,
            InstanceData = await cache.StringGetAsync(isForCallback ? $"Call_{id}" : id.ToString())
        };
        return callInstance;

    }
}
```

Comment: This is just a suggestion: look into a ```Windows Service``` or a database of some type. I believe you'll get what you're looking for there.  But if you have it resolved you have it resolved... It just doesn't seem to be the proper solution for what you're doing but who's to blame you if it's working right.

Comment: @MichaelPuckettII Thanks, I'll do that, actually I solved that problem in that way, maybe is not the best probably but maybe can help someone, anyway I just marked this as answered because nobody else came with something different. Again, Thanks!